# Is there a way to include JavaFX controlsFX in Intellij Scene Builder?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, controlsfx

I was wondering if there is a way to include *controlsfx* into the Scene Builder inside JetBrains Intellij. I tried to google it but I did not find anything relevant or updated.

Comment: just add the controlsfx jar file to the project libraries. then you can use the controls in it in the built-in scene builder.

Comment: IntelliJ and Scene Builder are two different applications. Are you looking to include ControlsFX in Scene Builder (so you can visually use its components) or just include the library in your Java project within IntelliJ?

Comment: @Zephyr, in intellij has built-in scene builder.

Comment: IntelliJ uses a scaled-down version of Scene Builder for its internal editor. The full version of Scene Builder offers the ability to import other library controls; I do not believe the built-in version has this capability.

Comment: the first comment of @mrmcwolf did the trick. As zephyr said the scaled-down version of Scene Builder included in Intellij has not the feature to import libraries (for example *controlsfx*). However following mrmcwolf steps I managed to add controlsfx into Intellij's Scene Builder and now I can work or run those kind of new components. mrmcwolf thanks again, you are helping me a lot! I wish to ask some questions via another private channel, but I do not know if you have the time or the will to help a newbie! Anyway thanks

Comment: @mrmcwolf answer the question -not in the comment- so i can close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just add the controlsfx jar file to the project libraries. then you can use the controls in it in the built-in scene builder

If you create user control in your project intellij will allow you to use it directly in the built-in scene builder just as you use external controls.

Comment: Which one to add?

Comment: java, maven ,kotlin?