# Use SceneBuilder with JavaFX 11 in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, javafx-11

I am using IDEA (with OpenJDK 11), and I am trying to use the SceneBuilder to display my FXML files. It works, except when I use inherited JavaFX components, for example :

```
public class MyLabel extends Label {
    public MyLabel(){
        super();
        setText("42");
    }
}
```

I always get an error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sample/MyLabel has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

So I looked in my IDEA installation folder (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\xxx.xxxx.xxx\plugins\javaFX\lib), and I saw that IDEA is using the version for Java 8 of the SceneBuilder ("SceneBuilderKit-8.2.0.jar").

I am wondering how I can use the [Java 11 version](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) in IDEA. I already tried to fill the SceneBuilder path in the parameters, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

If IntelliJ's embedded Scene Builder version is 8.2, then you can't expect that it can "render" any class in its classpath compiled for a Java version greater than 8 (level 52).

The embedded Scene Builder is just another Java application running, basically a JavaFX application running embedded in a Swing component on top of a IntelliJ editor.

**Java 8**

In order to work with regular FXML files that use built-in controls, Scene Builder uses the JDK to load the `jfxrt.jar` to the classpath.

If you create your own custom control using Java 8 (this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064426/add-custom-component-to-fxml-scene-builder-in-intellij) has a good sample on how to do this), and you *don't compile* the project, when you try Scene Builder you will get a `ClassNotFoundException`, because the control is not in the classpath, and Scene Builder doesn't know how to deal with it.

But after you build the project, the resulting classes are added to the classpath as well, and you can see the control rendered.

**Java 11**

When you create the custom control with Java 11, as you know, there is no more `jfxrt.jar`.

Following the Getting Started [docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx), you need to add the JavaFX 11 [SDK](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) to your project, and the VM options

```
--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

in order to run the project.

If you have a *regular* FXML file, with just built-in controls, and go to the embedded Scene Builder, it will load and render it. Why is that? Because it is probably using the internal JDK 1.8 shipped with IntelliJ, so the FXML file (containing pure xml, not a java file!) can be parsed by the (Java 8) `FXMLLoader` and rendered.

But if you try your custom control, after building the project, you will get the exception you mentioned:

[image: Scene Builder Exception]

since you are compiling with Java 11, and the level now is 55.

Is there any way to make it work? As mentioned before, all you need to do is load your control into the classpath, but with 52 level.

So all you need to do is set the target level of your project to 1.8, in Project Structure -> Project -> Project Language level

[image: Level 1.8]

Now build again your project, and you will be able to see the custom control with the embedded Scene Builder:

[image: Scene Builder with custom control]

Since your project is now compatible with Java 8, you can verify that you will be able to run:

```
/path-to-java-8/java -jar out/production/Custom_jar/Custom.jar
```

In any case, if you don't want that level, you can of course keep Java 11 and use the stand-alone [Scene Builder 11](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to José Pereda's answer,

in a Maven project, you need to set build > plugins > maven-compiler-plugin > configuration > release to 8, instead of 11

Answer (score 0):

Just try to install plugin "choose runtime" in the newest EAP 2019.3 version for Java 11 and CTRL-SHIFT-A choose choose-runtime and latest jbrsdk-8.
Choose in your project structure java 11, but with java 8 compatibility.

[Also use jfoenix 8.0.9 in your project to run scene builder.](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/582#issuecomment-359833891)
To run program use jfoenix 9.0.9.